# UICollectionViewCell button clicked and change text on cell

Tags: ios, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I want to change the button (`UIButton` is inside `UICollectionViewCell`)  text when I click on the button. How do I get the cell and the button?  I have a custom cell.

```
[cell.shareButton addTarget:self action:@selector(shareAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(void)shareAction:(UIButton*)button {
      NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:            [self.collectionView convertPoint:button.center fromView:button.superview]];
      NSLog(@"row %d",indexPath.row);
     NSLog(@"section %d",indexPath.section);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UIButton is the sender :

```
- (void)shareAction:(UIButton *)button {
    // the 'button' parameter is your required button.
    // now let's get the cell
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = button.superview.superview.
    // this is the cell
}
```

The 'cell' and 'button' variables are the pressed button, and it's cell.

Comment: +1  button.superView gets the contentView of the cell and it's superView is the UICollectionViewCell.